# How to make an Ajax call to action method in different controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following scenario.

Route Config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SellerRegistration",
    url: "Registration/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SellerRegistration", action = "Seller", id = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyCompany.Controllers" }
);
```

So when the url is `www.example.com/Registration/Seller`, the above route will match and displaying the view without any issues.

```
class SellerRegistration
{
   public ActionResult Seller()
   {
      return View("Seller");
   }

   [AjaxOnly]
    public bool ValidateUserEmail(string email)
    {
        return _userService.ValidateUserEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Inside my view `Seller.cshtml`, I'm trying to make an ajax call to the method `ValidateUserEmail()`.

I'm making ajax call as below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rootUrl + "/SellerRegistration/ValidateUserEmail",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: { email: $("#Email").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === 'True') {
                    //redirect to login page
                    window.location.href = newUrl;
                } else {
                    $("#otherDetails").show();
                    $("#emailValidation").hide();
                    $("#submitCompleteFormDiv").show();
                }
            },
            error: function (data, jqXhr) {
                console.log(jqXhr.status);
            }
        });
```

I have also tried generating url as below in the above ajax method.

```
url: '@Url.Action("SellerRegistration", "ValidateUserEmail")'
```

But I'm getting

> 401 - Unauthorised error.

I'm guessing that I'm not able to make ajax call because of the routing I configured. But, that routing is required to meet other scenarios in the application.

When ajax call is made, the url format is like `www.example.com/Registration/Seller`

So browser initiates an ajax call to the `ValidateUserEmail` method inside the controller `SellerRegistration` from `www.example.com/Registration/Seller`.

Because there is no real controller named `Registration`, when the ajax call is made to `ValidateUserEmail()` inside `SellerRegistration` controller, I'm getting 401 Unauthorized error.

Can someone please suggest if there is any technique or workaround to make it possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Show how your generating the url in your ajax call.

Comment: if you're getting 401, it's could well be routing ok, but 401 means the user doesn't have permission to call that method. As the previous commenter said, we need to see the client-side code making the ajax call

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've updated the question with client side ajax method. As ADyson mentioned, it is something to do with permission to call that method.

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("SellerRegistration", "ValidateUserEmail")'` would generate the correct url. And I assume its really `public class SellerRegistrationController : Controller`?

Comment: When a call has been made to the method "ValidateUserEmail", the referrer of that ajax call is www.example.com/Registration/Seller and the controller does not have any idea about the referrer (url). I guess this is where I'm having an issue with authorisation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes it is public Controller

Comment: I think you need to specify content type and datatype

Comment: because it is an authorisation issue, can we remove the **"ValidateUserEmail"** method from **"SellerRegistration"** controller and put it somewhere else where it can be accessed publicly?

Comment: you can declared your another route in class